# Robot Framework:: Imported library 'class' contains no keywords

Tags: python, robotframework

I am creating Robot Framework keyword using python
When I use only function, then RIDE can detect the keyword

```
def hello_world (patient):
  print ('Hello')
```

However when I am using

```
class helloAll(object):
 def hello_world (patient):
  print ('Hello')
```

I am adding the library as below

```
*** Settings ***

Library           hello
```

I have placed the `.py` file in the same directory as the test case.

```
Imported library "Name of the Class" contains no keywords
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake, I needed to put Library fileName.ClassName , it fixed the issue

Comment: If the class name matches the file name, you can drop the file name from the import.

Comment: @vieroli I do this: put my module in ./resource/Communications.py, inside create a class with the same name and added a method with decorator @keyword('my method') and works for me